# jQuery each call to other function

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am curious why this does not work.  This is more hypothetical but I did run into this issue on a site that I am doing.  I am trying to avoid a jQuery function inside a function.  The this selector is the window instead of each of the boxes.

EDIT*******
I DO UNDERSTAND HOW to do this doing the $(".box").each(function(){ // code here }); but is it not sloppy or bad practice functions inside of functions?

http://jsfiddle.net/B8Yp3/3/

CSS

```
.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: green;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
```

Javascript

```
 function changeMe(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        $(obj).css("background", "blue");
    }

    $.each($(".box"), changeMe(this));
```

Comment: `$.each($(".box"), changeMe);`

Comment: No; functions inside functions are perfectly normal.  Closures are one of Javascript's most important language features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second each paramater must be function - not function result:

```
$(".box").each(changeMe);

function changeMe(n, obj) { ........
```

Comment: If this approach is used the `changeMe()` function's parameters need to be changed.

Comment: you need to change `changeMe` signature to `changeMe(n, obj)`

Comment: What if you were to need to add an additional parameter, or should I just rely on doing that globally?

Comment: @Chad Then you'd use an anonymous function. There's no reason at all to purposefully avoid them.

Comment: Chad, you can't do that with this technique. You'd be able to do that with an anonymous function, however, as I've suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thanks i want to clean up my code and knowing that it is acceptable to do anonymous functions in there and not feel bad about it changes things for me.

Comment: @Chad you don't need to pass `this` as `changeMe` will get the right scope automatically (the '.box'). if you need to pass other data use an anonymous function

Answer (score 4):

When you call the `$.each` function,`this` still refers to the window object, as you noted. To have `this` refer to the jQuery object, you could call it in an anonymous function, which gets the proper scope applied.

```
$(".box").each(function(){ 
    changeMe(this); 
});
```

As a sidenote, it is absolutely not bad practice, sloppy, or anything negative whatsoever to call functions inside of other functions in Javascript. In fact, it's a cornerstone of Javascript programming (one of its most important concepts, callbacks, relies on functions inside of other functions). Functions are first-class citizens in Javascript, so they can be passed around, stuck inside other functions, and treated as any other object would be.

You may be interested in reading more about functions in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). They explain a lot about functions being objects, nesting functions, closures and more, which may interest you if you wish to understand how functions are best used.

Comment: I do understand that works and I have no problem with that but is it not sloppy or bad practice in javascript to have a function inside a function?

Comment: Absolutely not. In fact, it's one of the most important factors in Javascript.

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, it is indeed jQuery. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, I don't get the downvotes either. This is the correct answer and was also the first one to be posted. Edit: And apparently I'm the only one who has upvoted this till now!

Comment: *Thank* you, Dogbert. I'm mystified.

Comment: Im not sure the downvote either but I asked the question with lack of knowledge that it is perfectly normal to use anonymous functions.  I originally wanted an answer that did not use this method because I did originally use this.

Comment: Well, hopefully you'll come away with a better understanding of anonymous functions. I included a link to an article in the Mozilla documentation that might help you learn more, if you're interested. :)

Comment: Anyway in this case you should get rid of the `changeMe` function and just put its body inside the anonymous one. Unless you wanna call changeMe from somewhere else, in which case just use `$(".box").each(changeMe);`

Comment: and btw in this case you can simply do `$('.box').css("background", "blue")`

Comment: Note that functions inside functions cause JSLint to have a bit of a fit (in this case anyway, with each containing anonymous function.  I came here because I needed to call an external function, like the OP, in order to pass JSLint tests.  Actually the specific feedback was 57
"Don't make functions within a loop." and the $.each counts as a function and a loop, therefore function inside a functions if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Because the second parameter of `$.each` should be a `function`.

If you pass `changeMe(this)`, you are passing the return value of `changeMe` - you should wrap  it into an anonymous function:

```
 $.each($(".box"), function(){

    changeMe(this)

 });
```